# Can I use mvc filter attributes in webforms?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, aop, webforms, cross-cutting-concerns

I want to handle AOP aka cross cutting concerns with attributes ala MVC.
Do I have to use an AOP framework or something like Ninject which has an interception plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, need framework. I've found that if your domain models have references to each other, interception will work with ninject, unity, autofac, structuremap. If your domain models only reference an interface class library then only structure map worked for me.